# Can I have multiple full-screen OpenGL views (EAGLView) displayed at the same time on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, opengl, eaglview

Can I have 2 full-screen EAGLView-s (the OpenGL layer implementation from Apple's sample code), stack them on top of each other, draw on them independently and then see both images?

(I suppose the top one will need a glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0) to be transparent -- does that even work?!)

In my initial experiments, the 2nd EAGLView complains that there's an error trying to swap buffers (although glGetError() returns GL_NO_ERROR :) and, the the view that DOES display, the drawing is quite horked.

Am It attempting something that's completely not possible/supported?

Thanks!

Comment: why cannot you do this in one view?

Answer (score 0):

May be easier to use z-buffer ?

Or if you want use UILabel, etc, then add it in EAGL init.

Comment: I don't follow how Z-buffer will give me the ability to draw on 2 separate layers independently.